# TSQL Dynamic ordering of values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a dynamic query with a dynamic sorting over time filter that would create a descending sort order of the product items per value which in most of the cases is the expected.:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Time_Calculation ORDER BY SUM(T.[Displayed Value 1]) DESC) +2 end AS DisplayItem_SortOrder
```

Now the catch: I have a dataset type (this is set by a field in the WHERE clause) where negative numbers also come, and in this case I need to order from highest negative (ASC) to highest positive float datatype values.

 
The **ABS()** doesn't resolve this because then some positive numbers appear in the middle.
I tried to add a CASE statement but it seems that "ASC" and "DESC" is not something one can add inside the same.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Display Name    DisplayItem_SortOrder   Displayed Value 1
Product1    3   -31454.61396
Product10   4   -3407.16712
Product2    5   -708.9942251
Product3    6   123.5454381
Product6    7   428.6027531
Product5    8   454.4814295
Product4    9   454.9838374
Product9    10  455.54
Product8    11  471.54
```

Comment: Have you tried with the CASE in the ORDER BY? You should be able to sort with ASC and DESC that way.

Comment: Doesn't the regular ASC start from the lowest number (AKA highest negative) through the highest number (highest positive)? You shouldn't even need to specify ASC or DESC

Comment: The data you posted seems to be sorted an ascending order, isn't that good enough? Or do you want -708.994... to be the first value, and after that -3407.167...?

Comment: `order by Sign( Foo ), Abs( Foo )`? [`Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql).

Comment: @Habo Nice! I've been working with sql server since 2000 version, I don't remember even hearing of this function.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Another `Sign` trick: `Abs( Sign( Foo ) )` returns `1` for non-zero values, `0` for zero. An offset can be used to test for another specific value, e.g. `1 - Abs( Sign( Foo - 42 ) )` checks for [The Answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) and returns `1` for a match, `0` otherwise. (If used in code I would have a comment nearby to clarify the purpose.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

Create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS Table
(
    col int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (4), (-1), (-2), (-3), (5)
```

The query:

```
SELECT col
FROM @T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
         ABS(col)
```

Results:

```
col
-1
-2
-3
1
2
3
4
5
```